# load data into uipickerview with NSMutableArray located in app delegate

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, uipickerview

basically i have parsed some data from XML into a NSMutableArray that is shared in the appDelegate.

in my secondViewController i have a uiPickerView that i am wanting to load the details of the array into it.

My question is... how?

i have briefly worked with uiPickerView's before and had to load the data in first to assign to the uiPickerView like so:

```
titleDB = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[titleDB addObject:@"MR"];
[titleDB addObject:@"Mrs"];
[titleDB addObject:@"Ms"];
[titleDB addObject:@"Miss"];
[titleDB addObject:@"DR"];
[titlePickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

but since the data is coming from the appDelegate i don't know how i should load it into the uiPickerview, is it something to do with the datasource?

I'm asking to throw code at me I'm just asking for the best way to do it.

Any help on this would be great

Thanks
Jonn4y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to access the appDelegate object from random places in code.  This is not an unusual request.  Remember that Objective C is a superset of the C language.  And as such, you can use a global variable.  What more natural variable would there be in a Cocoa program than the app delegate, for the reasons stated above.  So, in your appDelegate .h file, add:

```
<MyAppDelegateClass> * appDelegate;
```

Substitute MyAppDelegateClass for the name of your appDelegate class name.  Then just include your appDelegate's .h file anywhere you want to use the appDelegate variable, and just use (in your example):

[appDelegate titleDB]

or create a local iVar:

NSMutableArray * titleDB = [appDelegate titleDBData];

Then in your app delegate method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, add the following line:

```
appDelegate = self;
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help, i have tried this and its all linked up correctly, when i call a NSLOG i can see the data from the database but when i try `countryDB = appDelegate.countries;` it crashes telling me `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BookPhoto isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d70440'
` BookPhoto is a file i was using to parse the XML in the first place so not sure why its being called here, i got the xml parsing from: http://www.iPhoneSDKArticles.com/2008/12/parsing-xml-files.html

Comment: countryDB is a NSMutableArray and countries is the NSMutableArray i have in my delegate (just so you know I'm not suppost to be using titleDB) cheers

Comment: Is BookPhoto a file?  Or a string?  isEqualToString: expects to have a string in front of it!

Comment: Also, I'm sorry, I left out a step.  In your application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in your appDelegate file, put the following statement at the beginning to set the global variable:     appDelegate = self;

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pattern.  You will want to access UIApplication's sharedApplication instance.  So assuming your appDelegate class is named YourAppDelegate, the array ivar in YourAppDelegate and viewController is titleDB then you could do this in your viewController's viewDidLoad method

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate=(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
// assuming you are using @property and @synthesize for your ivars
self.titleDB=appDelegate.titleDB;
```

Good luck